# How to get ImagePath after saving camera roll in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I get the image path after saving this on iPhone Camera Roll?

```
- (void)didTakeScreenshot:(UIImage*)screenshot  {
    strong textUIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

I have tried this code but the file is not existing.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, self, @selector(thisImage:hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:usingContextInfo:), nil);

- (void)thisImage:(UIImage *)image hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:(NSError *)error usingContextInfo:(void*)ctxInfo {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR:%@",error);`enter code here`
    } else {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Get Path : %@",documentsDirectory);

        //create Folder if Not Exist
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/YourFolder"];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

        NSString *yourPhotoName=@"YourPhotoName";
        NSString* path= [dataPath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.jpg",yourPhotoName]];
        NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); //which got from camera

        [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [prefs setObject:path forKey:@"keyToFindText"];
      
    }
}
```

Please anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reconsider your approach to saving the image. Also, it's not possible to get a path for later use from Photos. Rather store the local identifier and use it to retrieve the PHAsset object later.

Refer to [PhotoKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/browsing_and_modifying_photo_albums#3569958)
& [PHPlaceholderObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phobjectplaceholder)

### Writing to Photos

```swift
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    let creationRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
    if let assetCollection = self.assetCollection {
        let addAssetRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: assetCollection)
        addAssetRequest?.addAssets([creationRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset!] as NSArray)
    let placeHolderAsset = creationRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
    let localID = placeHolderAsset.localIdentifier // Save this value
    }
}, completionHandler: {success, error in
    if !success { print("Error creating the asset: \(String(describing: error))") }
})
```

### Retrieving

Refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset/1624732-fetchassets)

```swift
let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: yourSavedLocalID, options: nil).first
```